# Reverse DNS PTR

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, godaddy

I see a lot of information on reverse DNS, but I need an explanation of a definition.

Who is my ISP if...

```
I own a Web / Email server (apache2 / postfix / dovecot)
on a static IP (through comcast) 
with DNS managed by GoDaddy (not BIND on the server)
```

Comment: https://www.jacobdevans.com/fcrdns-reverse-pointer-isp-email-addresses/

Answer (score 1):

In the situation you describe, your ISP is Comcast.

If you need a Reverse DNS entry, Comcast are the ones you need to contact.

Comment: Thank you. I have found no clarity on this at all with many hours and many times looking. I appreciate your patience and tolerance, sometimes a clear, straightforward definition is needed, and users like you (answering, rather than down-voting with no explanation) make this site great.